# git log --format: linebreak after list of refs

Tags: git, git-log, git-format

the git log `format` option `%d` for displaying the list of refs associated with the commit accepts a `+` to add a "conditional" line break in front of this part of the output:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --date=short \
--format=format:"%C(dim white)%h%C(reset) %C(blue)%ad%C(reset) %C(bold white)%s%C(auto)%+d%C(reset)"
```

This results in a output like this, where the ref names are in a new line after the commit they belong to and no new line if there is no ref annotation for the commit:

[image]

This is somewhat misleading and makes the ouput harder to read than I wanted to have it.

I'd like to change the positions of the ref names to be the first part:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --date=short \
--format=format:"%C(auto)%+d%C(reset)%C(dim white)%h%C(reset) %C(blue)%ad%C(reset) %C(bold white)%s"
```

But then (obvious) I still get a linebreak *before* the refs and no linebreak behind.
If I add `%n` I get an *unconditional* linebreak resulting in an empty line between each and every commit, what I don't want either.

How can I place such a "conditional" line break **behind** the refs part, so that the ref is in a separate line before its commit, but no linebreake when the commit has no refs?

I already use this command in a shell script so any solution based on `sed` or `awk` **that preserves coloring** is also welcome.

Comment: Would you be okay with an extra line before each commit, that either contains the refs or is empty?

Comment: @knittl: No, I want a "condensed" view not scattered with empty lines. I'm currently think of replacing the commit part and the refs part using sed, seaching for a suitable regexp...

Comment: (my comment about `%-d` doesn't work as I expected)

Comment: @LeGEC: I already tried that too so at least it's not only me having this idea... ;o)

Comment: While Git's `%` directives in log formatting are pretty clever, they ultimately leave something to be desired. Mercurial handled this properly, for some definition of proper, but Mercurial's formatting directives were super-painful. There doesn't seem to be a good compromise available...

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem to be possible the way you want. The format specifiers of Git simply don't support that use case. You can only add an unconditional line break:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --date=short \
--format=format:"%C(auto)%d%n%C(reset)%-C(dim white)%h%C(reset) %C(blue)%ad%C(reset) %C(bold white)%s"
*  (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
| 79f2338b37 2022-09-05 The eighteenth batch
*   
|\  27fb520ef2 2022-09-05 Merge branch 'jk/test-crontab-fixes'
| * 
| | 0682bc43f5 2022-08-30 test-crontab: minor memory and error handling fixes
* |   
|\ \  fcbc8743ef 2022-09-05 Merge branch 'en/test-without-test-create-repo'
| * | 
| | | 6693fb3f01 2022-08-26 t64xx: convert 'test_create_repo' to 'git init'
* | |
```